# How to make jmunit run all tests and still fail at the end if any tests failed

Tags: unit-testing, ant, java-me, junit

When I switch off `haltonfailure` or `haltonerror` in my jmunit tests like this:

```
<jmunit haltonerror="false" haltonfailure="false" failureproperty="testfailure">
    <formatter type="xml" />
    <classpath>
        <path path="${jar_location}" />
        <path path="${build}" />
    </classpath>
    <!-- Add  -->
    <test name="com.example.tests.Test1" todir="${reports}" />
    <test name="com.example.tests.Test2" todir="${reports}" />
    <test name="com.example.tests.Etc" todir="${reports}" />
</jmunit >
```

The build succeeds even when some tests failed. If I turn the halts on, then of course it halts immediately upon the first failure.  The behaviour I want is that all tests are executed regardless of how many of them fail, but if ANY of them failed then the build won't be successful. The reason I want this is so that the reports can correctly show how many passes and failures, and which tests are failing.

How do I achieve this?
and/or
Is my thinking that I want all of the tests to be run flawed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy peasy:

You need to add the command

```
<fail message="Something went wrong. Please check the test results." if="testfailure" />
```

to the target that contains your jmunit command after the jmunit command itself.

This way, the jmunit task will set the variable `testfailure` when one of the tests fails and the command `fail` will make the build unsuccessful if that property is set.

Hope that helps.